# executing unix code from the terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, mac

I have a directory on my hard drive that contains a collection of Unix executable files that I am trying to run from the terminal. When I browse the directory from the terminal it shows all the files are there but when I enter the name of one of the Unix executables it says '-bash orca: command not found'(the executable is called 'orca'). If I browse to the folder in the finder and click on that same file, a terminal window appears and runs the file.  However, because the program requires that I specify an input file, I get the following returned:

```
/Users/damonrobles/Documents/orca_macosx_r2360/orca ; exit;
Damon-Robless-MacBook-Pro:~ damonrobles$ /Users/damonrobles/Documents/orca_macosx_r2360/orca ; exit;
This program requires the name of a parameterfile as argument
For example ORCA TEST.INP 
logout

[Process completed]
```

According to the program manual, I should call the program from the terminal as follows:

```
nohup orca Inputfile.inp >& outputfile.out
```

but when I do this it simply generates an output file that says:

```
nohup: orca: No such file or directory
```

and returns me to the terminal prompt. I can't figure out what the heck the problem is, although I am a novice terminal user so I'm sure it's something dumb on my part. Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm on a MacBook Pro, running OSX 10.6.8.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to use `./orca` instead of just `orca`. In OS X, the current directory (`.`) isn't in `$PATH` by default, so you can't execute programs in the current directory without explicitly naming it.

Comment: @Damon Robles: If you're thinking you can just add `.` to `$PATH`, that can be done but it's a security risk; it makes it easier for people to fool you into executing their malicious program instead of the standard one. So don't.

Comment: @Tom Zych: I'd never considered the security risk of doing that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: always have a well-prepared `sl` binary in your homedir, you never know who might run it one day...

Comment: @mvds +2 if I could :D

Comment: If you're not on a shared machine, the risk is pretty much 0; to get a malicious executable onto your machine the attacker will have to already have completely pwned you.

Comment: @Wooble - What if you run a malicious script in your browser?  It'll run with your permissions and can write files to your home directory tree.

Comment: @Tom: browsers generally sandbox javascript so it can't write to the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @jtbandes answer:  you can (1) navigate to the directory containing `orca` (as you say) and do as he says, you can (2) use a full path to the executable like /Users/Damon/foo/bar/orca (or to the input file for that matter), or you can "link" the executable to a directory that's on your $PATH.  For instance, if `orca` was on the Desktop, you could do:

```
mkdir bin
PATH=$PATH:~/bin;  export PATH
echo $PATH
ln -s ~/Desktop/orca ~/bin
ls -al ~/bin
orca infile > outfile
```

To make this permanent, you would alter `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add

```
/Users/damonrobles/Documents/orca_macosx_r2360
```

to your PATH environment variable, if you are going to leave the code installed under your Documents directory.

Another option you can consider is to add '`.`' to your PATH.

Although it can be dangerous (to add '`.`' to PATH), I work in sufficiently clean environments that I have '`.`' at the *front* of my PATH.  That is more dangerous than having it at the *back* of PATH, and both of these are more dangerous than not having '`.`' on your PATH.

The advantage of having '`.`' at the front is that while developing a program, I don't have to specify `./program` to run the local copy instead of the installed copy.  The disadvantage of having '`.`' at the front is that if someone gets onto my machine and creates a Trojan Horse called '`ls`' (say) in one of my directories and I run '`ls`' in that directory, I run their Trojan Horse instead of the real version.  If they've got any sense, the Trojan will clean up behind itself and run the intended command, meaning I might not notice.  It is up to you whether you consider that a serious risk or not.  Adding '`.`' at the end of PATH means that you'll run programs in the current directory that have no analogue anywhere else in your PATH; however, if you have an installed version of the program in, say, `/usr/local/bin` (and that is on your PATH), then the installed version will be run in preference to the local version.  That may or may not matter to you; it does to me so I put the '`.`' at the front, but it is a considered and understood risk.

YMMV; be cautious.